# Migration doesn't work for my PHP Laravel application

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem with my Laravel application.
When I type PHP artisan migrate this shows:

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Hte inconnu.  (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel8 and table_nam e = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\emart\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:742
    738▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    739▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    740▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    741▕         catch (Exception $e) {   ➜ 742▕             throw new QueryException(
    743▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    744▕             );
    745▕         }
    746▕     }

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\emart\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Hte inconnu. ")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\emart\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct()
```

I have already uncommented the "extension=pdo_mysql" in my php.ini and the extension_dir too

I also added the PHP to the path system But still doesn't work.

I have 2 php.ini files xampp\php\php.ini and \Program Files\php-8.1.5-Win32-vs16-x64\php.ini

Comment: Please include you mysql database configuration from `config/database.php` and from `.env` file. The error is regarding not able to connect to the mysql server

Comment: `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed` - it can't find whatever host you have for the database.

Comment: I included mysql database configuration , now i get this :                                         `Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table

   ErrorException 

  Undefined array key 0
`